# Angular 8 - routing works locally, but when deployed on Production, routes don't work - .NET Core C# backend

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, routes

In my app I created routes, they work perfectly on localhost, I can navigate to:

```
localhost:4200/about
```

but when deployed on Production, if I navigate to:

```
myapp.com/about
```

what will happen is, the browser would almost instantly rewrite the URL to: `myapp.com/index.html` and then right afterwards the final url I will see displayed in the navigation bar of the browser, will be the default path: "myapp.com/"

My routing code is:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "about", component: AboutComponent },
  { path: "**", redirectTo: "/" },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
      RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and I app module I also added, as I read it could help:

`providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]`,

on the backEnd side (frontend and backend are in the same project) this is the code:

```
public void Configure(
....
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" 
            });
            });
           app.UseSpa(spa => {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "FrontEnd";
                if (env.IsDev()) {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

the `HomeController`:

```
  public IActionResult Index() => Redirect("index.html");
```

the `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So basically whenever deployed, if I try to navigate to my route "`/about`", it will just rewrite to `index.html` and then redirect to "/"

Any ideas?

Comment: `ng build --prod` could you applied --prod flag when building you angular app?

Comment: yes I do, this is my docker command to build the image: "RUN npm run build -- --prod
"

Comment: in the network tab from Chrome, when I try to reach my route, I see that the Get Request gets Error code 302, and then Index..html gets requested

Comment: `{ path: "", redirectTo: "/", pathMatch: "full" },` here, `redirectTo:/` is not required.

Comment: removed it but same issue

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4keNnVxOh_M go through this link may be helpful to you!!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me but on an IIS server. Create a web.config file and place it in the root folder of Angular dist files.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <configuration>
         <system.webServer>
           <rewrite>
           <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />   
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="/frontend/" />//Folder with my Angular files
          </rule>
         </rules>
       </rewrite>
         </system.webServer>
      </configuration>
```